# Do convergence in distribution along with uniform integrability imply convergence of mean?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Thorem about necessary and sufficient condition for $L_1$ convergence states that $X_n$ - non negative,  $EX_n$ converges to $EX$ if and only if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability and $X_n$ is uniformly integrable.

But there is Corollary of the Theorem - the same but with **convergence in distribution**. How can it be proven?

Also thos proven for weak convergence.

In book of Patric Billigsley I found this:

> Every result about weak convergence has an anologue about convergence
>   in distribution,and vice versa, and to pass from the oneto the other
>   requires not a proof, but merelya translation.

Comment: Probably the corollary has also some other extra condition, like that the $X_n$ converge to a constant $c$ or something like that. Otherwise it does not make any sense

Comment: no, there is only $X_n\ge 0$

Comment: your question is not clear, you begin by citing theorem in $L^1$ convergence but then changes to convergence of $EX_n$ to $EX$. If we know only $EX_n \to EX$ we can say nothing about if $X_n \to X$ in probability

Comment: We know theorem with convergence in probability and uniformly integrable, and it can be proven $EX_n \to EX$. Not we should proof similar statement, but with convergence in distribution.